# How can I find the current screen size of my CarPlay screen?

Tags: swift, carplay

I wonder how to find the current screen size of the CarPlay screen

In iOS we can write UIScreen.main.bound and it will give the current screen size of an iphone. This does not work in CarPlay simulator.
I tried different versions of screen bounds as well such as

1. interfaceController.accessibilityFrame.size
2. templateApplicationScene.carWindow.screen.bounds
   etc. Nothing works

Comment: Are you testing on a simulator or real device? What is the output of the methods you tried?